# creating individual divs and populating them using ajax and php without data repeating itself

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 10 attractions for each city, and when I search for a city I want these attractions to appear in separate divs. So for example I would like big ben, and the details about big ben to appear on the left hand side of the screen, and then Buckingham palace and its details  on the right hand side. However when I click search all the data from the database is being pulled into one div and it is repeating itself over and over for some reason. So at the minute there is a big long list at the left hand side of the screen.

I am using ajax, and php to populate the page with data. Here is my ajax code

```
 $('#submit').on('click', function() {
var search = $('#search').val();

    if ($.trim(search) != '') { //if search is not equal to nothing - using trim allows users to type in blank space and it won't return anything 
        $.post('searching.php', {search: search}, function(data) {
            $('#return').text(data);
    });
    }
 });
```

Here is my php code

```
require_once('config1.php');


$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search']) === true && empty($_POST['search']) === false){



$query = ("SELECT a.attraction_name, a.lat, a.long, a.cost, a.image FROM zz_attractions a INNER JOIN zz_city c ON a.city_id = c.city_id WHERE c.city_name = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['search'])) . "' ");


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 0) { 
    $output = 'there was no search results';

} else {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $attraction_name = $row['attraction_name'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $long = $row['long'];
    $cost = $row['cost'];
    $image = "<img src='{$row['image']}' height='100' width='100'>";

 echo $output .= '<div>'.$attraction_name.' '.$lat.' '.$long.' '.$cost.' '.$image.'</div>';

    }
}
}
```

And this is my html div

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div id="return"></div> 

</div>
```

If anyone has any idea how I can separate the data into individual divs please tell me, thanks.

Comment: How do you expect to distribute your results among several divs when your PHP code sends back a bunch of them all at once? Anyway, not sure how exactly you want this to work. Are you going to have two or three fixed divs, then put the first two or three results into them?

Comment: @ChrisG Thats what I am asking how to do, I am not sure how I separate my php and database so I get one attraction to one div. There is always going to be 10 attractions being shown, so I would like to create 10 divs, and give them ids of attraction1, attraction2 for example, but I don't know how to individually call each attraction to a separate div

Comment: Don't `echo` in the `while` loop. Echo once you've built up **all of your markup**.

Comment: I'd change the PHP code so it sends back an array containing just the data. You can use JSON to send that data to the browser. On the JS side, iterate over the received array and build each div from that.

Comment: Right! Your PHP loop echoes 1, then 1 and 2, then 1,2 and 3, and so on. Either use `echo '<div...>'` *in* the loop, or use `$output .= '<div...>;` then `echo $output` *after* the loop.

Comment: I have a feeling some of the Bootstrap isn't being applied properly either.

Comment: Fixed the loop: https://ideone.com/1QP37I

Comment: @ChrisG When ever I echo outside of the while loop only the first row of data appears

Comment: Not if your code properly appends each row to  `$output`.

Comment: @ChrisG I copied and pasted your code, and it is showing all the images first and then the attractions. Will I be able to fix this with JSON? When I apply each attraction to each div?

Comment: @hungerstar What bootstrap isn't being applied? And how to I fix it? It looks ok in the browser

Comment: The key is to implement this properly and cleanly. What you describe could simply be caused by faulty CSS (which we cannot see).

Comment: @ChrisG I haven't touched the css but hungerstar said that some of my bootstrap might not be working, could this be the reason why it is displaying the images first?

Comment: @SSS12_ The altered loop shouldn't have changed the shape of the `<div>`s, just fixed the repetition. I did remove the `width='100' height='100'`, which can be easily done with a basic CSS rule.

Comment: Well I will try do the json stuff and then see if I am still having this problem. Thanks very much